# Changing directory using OS module in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to read all .csv files in a directory using Python. So when I googled it, I got this solution 
[Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-with-python)

But when I entered

```
import glob
import os
os.chdir("/Desktop")
```

I am getting the following error

```
>>> os.chdir("~/Desktop")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Desktop'
```

I am really confused where am I wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your code sample, you wrote `os.chdir("/Desktop")`, but in the error message it says `os.chdir("~/Desktop")`. Which one did you actually type?

Comment: sry its a typo :( ... i entered later

Answer (score 3):

You need to expand `~` to actual home directory using [`os.path.expanduser`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
'/home/falsetru/Desktop'
```

Otherwise, `~` mean the directory `~` (literally `~`).

Answer (score 0):

`os.chdir` doesn't do tilde expansion. You need

```
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getenv("HOME"), "Desktop"))
```

to go to `~/Desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import os   
>>> os.chdir('~/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Desktop'
>>> os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop'))
>>> os.getcwd()
'/users/xxx/Desktop'
```